# How can we get report of the items with no reference or links in Sitecore 8.2?

Tags: item-name

I need a PowerShell script or a .aspx page to get the list of items which has no reference or link to it. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/delete-data-sources-without-any-referrers

Comment: Yes this helps partially. But will be helpful if I get something like a report or a aspx page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using powershell you can take a look at the `Get-ItemReferrer` documentation https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/common/get-itemreferrer that can be used check if an item has any referrences to it. I have used the following powershell script:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path 'master:/sitecore/content/Home' -Recurse
$results = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($item in $items) {
    $links = $item | Get-ItemReferrer

    if ($links.Count -eq 0) {
        [void]$results.Add($item)
    }
}

$results | Format-Table Name, @{ Label = 'Path'; Expression={ $_.Paths.Path } }
```

In C# you can use `ItemLink[] itemLinks = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item);` to get all referrers of a specific item. I would also recommend to run `Rebuild Link databases` from control panel prior to running the reports to make sure Link Database is up to date.